# how to use fullscreen mode within iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, fullscreen

I am using your [screenfull](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js) lib and so far all is fine. I would like however to continue its usage within iframe and I am stuck.
Please see JSFiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/80jk6906/ and tell me when I am wrong.

Here is the code snippet:

```
<iframe src="http://sindresorhus.com/screenfull.js/" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="400px" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that code snippet does not work under JSFiddle only. 
Just to summarize - provided code snippet works just fine in everywhere but from JSFiddle.